# Sql to generate all combination from 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have 3 tables

```
Table1:         Table2:       Table3:     
**Users**       **Posts**     **Articles**

Name|           Title|        Title|
Raj             Post1         Article1
Sujay           Post2         Article2
Bijay           Post3         Article3
Jijay           Post4         Article4
```

Now I want to do combine all possible combination of them and put it into another table

Like I want to put it in a table tmp_all_cobinations

```
Table: **tmp_all_combinations**

Name
Raj.Post1.Aticle1
Raj.Post1.Aticle2
Raj.Post1.Aticle3
Raj.Post1.Aticle4
Raj.Post2.Aticle1
...
Raj.Post3.Aticle1
....
Sujay.

....
```

in this way

Comment: try `select * from users, Posts, articles`

Comment: Hi Jns thanks for you comment can you please laborate how can I store it after select

Comment: @RajarshiDas - why store it in a fourth table? you are duplicating the data, and you'll need to rebuild it on every change to this table. it is much better as a query, or to create a view that runs this query

Comment: What database are you actually using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a cross join between the three tables, which in MySQL can be achieved by doing an `INNER JOIN` with no `ON` restriction.

```
INSERT INTO tmp_all_combinations (Users, Posts, Articles)
SELECT t1.Users, t2.Posts, t3.Articles
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table3 t3
```

If you are using Postgres, then you can replace `INNER JOIN` with `CROSS JOIN` to get the same result.

If the `tmp_all_combinations` does not already exist, you can create it, making sure the columns have the same types as the three source tables.

Comment: @RajarshiDas I am OK, but no one is as good as [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) when it comes to writing SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

The ANSI-SQL way to address this would be to use a `cross join`:

```
INSERT INTO tmp_all_combinations
SELECT      table1.name, table2.title, table3.title
FROM        table1
CROSS JOIN  table2
CROSS JOIN  table3
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need is a join without any columns to join on, so it will be all columns on all columns. so it's simply:

```
select * from users, Posts, articles
```